# rosjava: gradle or rosmake?

Tags: ros, gradle, rosjava, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to set up rosjava by following the tutorial released by Google [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html).
Upon installing rosjava_core, I look to [this  ROS wiki tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build) to create my first package and build it and eventually import it into Eclipse as documented in [this ROS wiki tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build/Eclipse).

The Eclipse tutorial states that my Eclipse .project and .classpath files would automatically be created upon running rosmake, but they are not. Going back to Google's tutorials, I notice there are conflicting directions to remove the generated Makefile and CMakeLists.txt files rather than edit them, as the ROS wiki tutorial suggests.
One of these tutorials is outdated. Which? Is gradle the new standard for building rosjava packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36108/rosjava:-gradle-or-rosmake?/) by [DGonz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2579/dgonz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current rosjava build system uses Gradle, and its use is documented here: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html

I've annotated the wiki page you referenced to highlight this.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3